# how to make divs stop overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got two main divs in my page: the first one contains an accordion menu and the second one, the main text of the page. When I resize the browser window, **both divs overlap each other**, like in this picture:

[image: Divs overlap each other!]

**How can I make that stop?** I searched a lot to find an answer, but nothing worked. I tried to add `overflow: auto;`, `float: left`, I played with the margin... Without success.

Here is my code:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
body#help {
    font-size: 3vmin;
    /*Background*/
    background: #444444; /* For browsers that [are shit enough to] do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1a8cff, #4da6ff); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1a8cff, #4da6ff); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1a8cff, #4da6ff); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#1a8cff, #4da6ff); /* Standard syntax */
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel {
    background-color: #666666;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    width:250px;
}

#helpMenuDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    left: 0px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 840px;
    order: solid 2px black;
    overflow: auto;
}

.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

#helpPageDiv {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="helpHtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body id="help">

<!---Introduction--->    
    
    <div id="helpPageDiv">
       <p>Content of the first div (main text)</p>
    </div>
    
<!---Accordion--->
    <div id="helpMenuDiv">
        <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
        <p class="panelText">Content of the accordion</p>
        </div>

        <!---More accordions--->
    
    <script src="scripts/accordion.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Try: `sidenav push (off canvas)` at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for, I will try when I can, thanks

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by not overlap. You want a `min-width` and add a `margin-left` the width of the accordion when you click the button?

Comment: @PHPglue I mean that I do not want #helpPageDiv (which contains page's content) and #helpMenuDiv (the accordion) to overlap each other, I would like them to collide instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions.

1. You can give your `helpPageDiv` a left margin equal to the width of `helpMenuDiv` using Jquery that changed with window resize.

---

2. Try giving width to both `helpMenuDiv` and `helpPageDiv` and make them float left. Also you can put your menu above the content div in small screens.

Here's I created a simple example that might be useful to you.
[>>> JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shalika247/th4w6cne/).
Try resizing the result window too.

```js
$('.menu .menu-item h3').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('p').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.holder:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #64c1be;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #73c379;
}
.content .inner{
  color: #4d4d4d;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu .menu-item {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.menu .menu-item h3 {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .menu-item p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 3px;
  display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 550px){
  .menu, .content{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="menu">
    Accordian menu
    <div class="menu-item">
      <h3>
        + Section 1
      </h3>
      <p>
        Menu content
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h3>
        + Section 2
      </h3>
      <p>
        Text Text
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="menu-item">
      <h3>
        + Section 3
      </h3>
      <p>
        faucibus orci
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="menu-item">
      <h3>
        + Section 4
      </h3>
      <p>
        ullamcorper 
      </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    Content goes here
    <div class="inner">
      Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without JQuery? I would like to use pure JS (CSS only would be even better)

Comment: I used jQuery for the menu toggle part. You already have a method to do it. So you can use it. For your question div overlapping, done by CSS only.